# Lower semi-continuity of a convex functional on $L^1(\Omega,[0,1])$

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity, convex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain and $f:\Omega\times[0,1]\to[0,\infty]$ be such that
$x\mapsto f(x,u)$ is measurable for every $u$, $u\mapsto f(x,u)$ is continuous and convex for a.e. $x$. Furthermore $f(x,0)=0$ and  $f(x,1)=\infty$.

Define the "functional"  $$F(v)=\int_\Omega f(x,v(x)) dx$$ with $F:M_f\to[0,\infty]$ where $M_f:=\{v\in L^\infty(\Omega,[0,1])\colon f(\cdot,v)\in L^1(\Omega)\}$. This set is a subset of any $L^p$ space.

I want to show, that tis functional is weakly lower semi continuous in some $L^p$ for some $p\in[1,\infty)$. For this, it suffices to show that $M_f$ is a convex set and that$F$ is strongly lower semi-continuous and convex. The convexity is clear but I have problems with the lower semicontinuity.

For me, this looks somehow like Fatou's Lemma but somehow there seems to be a flaw in my idea:

Let $v_k\to v\in L^p$ with $v_k,v\in M_f$. Hence $\liminf F(v_k)=:C$ exists. Consequently, there is a subsequence $k'$ with $\lim_{k'\to\infty} F(v_{k'})=C$. Furthermore, due to the strong convergence of $v_k\to v$ the subsequence can be chosen such that $v_{k'}\to v$ pointwise almost everywhere.

Now the limit is of course a lim inf. Hence we can apply Fatou's lemma
$$\lim F(v_k')\geq \int_\Omega \liminf_{k'} f(x,v_{k'}(x))=F(v)$$
where we used the continuity of $f$ and the pointwise convergence of $v_k\to v$.

Is Fatou's lemma applicable in this case? Is there any hidden trap in the continuity of $f$ in $1$? As far as I understand it, one can just choose the standard topology on $[0,\infty]$ that contains the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and hence the continuity in $[0,1)$ is the classical continuity; the continuity in $1$ is described by the extended topology (i.e. neighborhoods at $\infty$), right?

Edit: What one could add or what is puzzling me it could be that $F(v)\geq F(\liminf v_k)$ since the $v_k$ do not need to converge pointwise to $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is fine. You have a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions $x\mapsto f(x,v_{k'}(x))$. They converge a.e. to $f(x,v(x))$ (due to $v_{k'}\to v$ pointwise and   the continuity of $f$ in the second variable). Hence, Fatou's lemma applies and yields 
$$\int f(x,v(x))\,dx\le \liminf \int f(x,v_{k'}(x)) \,dx$$

> What is puzzling me it could be that $F(v)\ge F(\liminf v_k)$

Sure, that could happen. But $\liminf v_k$ has little to do with convergence in $L^p$. Here is a concrete  example: let $\Phi(v)=\|v\|_{L^p}$ and consider the sequence $$v_k=1-\chi_{[j/2^r, (j+1)/2^r]},\quad r=\lfloor \log_2 k\rfloor,\ j = k-2^r$$
Here $v_k\to 1$ in $L^p$ but $\liminf v_k\equiv 0$. Thus, $\Phi(\lim v_k )>\Phi(\liminf v_k)$ despite $\Phi$ being as nice a functional as one may wish.

Comment: Is there a chance to show continuity for the functional? The reverse inequality with Fatou's lemma fails. Somehow i expected that since $f$ is continuous one would also obtain that $F$ is. Also in your example, the norm is strongly continuous (but onle weakly lower semi continuous).

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 It need not be strongly continuous. For example, take $$f(x,u) = \frac{1}{1-x}\frac{u}{1-u}$$ Let $v_k=\frac12 \chi_{I_k}$ where $I_k\subset [0,1]$ is some interval  moving toward $1$ as $k$ increases. Choose $I_k$ so that $F(v_k)=0.1$ for all $k$. You will notice that $I_k$ shrinks in length as $k\to \infty$ (because $f$ has the factor $1/(1-x)$). Thus, $v_k\to 0$ in $L^p$ despite $F(v_k)$ not converging to $0$.